# Create List WorkFlow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I want to create list workflow in SharePoint designer 2013 there is no Sharepoint 2013 in Platform Type, while I am using Sharepoint  2013.
SP designer notifies this message:
The option for the SP 2013 workflow is not available because the workflow service is not configured on the server. Please contact your server administrator.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for the SharePoint 2013 workflow option to appear that you'll need to install and configure workflow for SharePoint Server 2013. Here's the step-by-step way to install it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

Comment: First, thank you for your response, but when I am follow the instructions in the Video which is located in the link. In part 3, where they are request for a certificate, I have following problems: Instead of Windows server 2012, I am using windows 8 for workflow manager. However in MMC and certificate --> Personal there is no any certificate and when I am requesting I get this message: Certificate Types are Available. Please give me a solution